# Google+ send invitation message from app

Tags: android, google-plus

In my android app, I wish to allow user to invite friends from different social platforms. User already can invite friends from Facebook, VK, from his contacts list on phone, but I can't find way to send invite message to Google+. Is this really possible? Or maybe I can send message somehow using google_id?

I don't need to post on my wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/prefill#prefill_the_recipients_of_a_post).

There is a `setRecipients` method, which allows you to share it only with a few persons. It's not the same as private messaging, and it will appear on the wall (only for you and those persons), but it looks like G+ is supposed to make it this way.

Comment: Yeah, I've found that out, maybe I'll message in Hangouts then.